# Notion Formula with multiple if statements

Tags: if-statement, formula, notion

Can anyone help me fix my Notion formula? I am trying to create a database of all my contacts and reminders to follow up with people. Depending on the type of association, I want to check in after a different duration of time. Everything is working fine except for the "Best Friends" and "Immediate Family" section of the formula. No matter the date of the "Last Contacted" column, it always outputs "Time to check in!"

> `if((prop("Association") == "Friend" or prop("Association") == "Professional" or prop("Association") == "Mentor") and dateBetween(now(), prop("Last Contacted"), "months") > 5, "Time to check in!", if(prop("Association") == "Family" or prop("Association") == "Life-long Friend" and dateBetween(now(), prop("Last Contacted"), "months") > 0, "Time to check in!", if(prop("Association") == "Best Friends" or prop("Association") == "Immediate Family" and dateBetween(now(), prop("Last Contacted"), "weeks") > 1, "Time to check in!", "")))`

I have tried changing the duration to "months" as to copy the previous if statements, however even that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try changing the datebetween difference to days i.e 1 month = 30 days I find thats a lot more accurate.